# str object has no attribute day error

Tags: python, csv, opencsv

Here's my code. Not sure what the issue is. Where do I get the day attribute for the CSV file? does it need to be added in filtering?

```
import apache_log_parser

from pandas import DataFrame


parser = apache_log_parser.make_parser('%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s')

data = {'day': [],
        'time': []}

with open('coursework.csv') as in_f:

    reader = DictReader(in_f)
    for line in reader:
        identifier = '%s_%s' % (line['time_received_isoformat'], line['remote_host'])

        data['day'].append(line['time_received_isoformat'].day)
        if 'search' in line['request_url_path']:
            data['category'].append('search')
        elif 'browse' in line['request_url_path']:
            data['category'].append('browse')
        elif 'add-to-cart' in line['request_url_path'] or 'remove-from-cart' in line['request_url_path']:
            data['category'].append('cart')
        elif 'book' in line['request_url_path']:
            data['category'].append('item')
        elif line['request_url_path'] == '/baseline/':
            data['category'].append('baseline')
        elif line['request_url_path'] == '/explore/' or line['request_url_path'] =='/review/':
            data['category'].append('modern')
        else:
            print(line['request_url_path'])
print(data['day'])
```

Comment: The value of `line['time_received_isoformat']` is of type string, and hence doesn't have the attribute `.day`

Comment: Why would the value in column `time_received_isoformat` have a `day` attribute?

Comment: I want use the time_received_isoformat to make a graph of what days users are on the site. Is there no way I can use that data in the CVS file?